# How to add continuously change color of container in flutter between RGB values

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, rgb

I want to create an animation where the container changes colors just the LED lights do in real life.
I this would be automatic so I dont want any 'onPressed()' working classes

I tried doing it through 'Timer' and 'AnimatedContainer()' but the timer only responds to initState value i.e. 0

Either help me setState the state of Container after every second or give me some another solution.

This is my code currently

```
 late Timer timer;
  int start = 0;

  void startTimer() {
    const oneSec = Duration(seconds: 1);
    timer = Timer.periodic(
      oneSec,
      (Timer timer) {
        setState(() {
          start++;
        });`your text`
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startTimer();
    setState(() {
      _changeColor();
    });
  }

  _changeColor() {
    setState(() {
      if (start % 3 == 0) {
        changingColor = Colors.green;
      } else if (start % 3 == 1) {
        changingColor = Colors.blue;
      } else if (start % 3 == 2) {
        changingColor = Colors.red;
      }
    });
      }
```

Comment: I think you should call the `_changeColor()` method directly in `Timer.periodic` callback

Comment: Use 'AnimatedContainer' -->  https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedContainer-class.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `setState` for `start` won't call `_changeColor`, so you have to call `_changeColor` inside `Timer`.

```dart
class LEDWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const LEDWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<LEDWidget> createState() => _LEDWidgetState();
}

class _LEDWidgetState extends State<LEDWidget> {
  Color changingColor = Colors.green;
  int start = 0;
  late Timer timer;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (_) {
      start++;
      _changeColor();
    });
  }

  _changeColor() {
    setState(() {
      if (start % 3 == 0) {
        changingColor = Colors.green;
      } else if (start % 3 == 1) {
        changingColor = Colors.blue;
      } else if (start % 3 == 2) {
        changingColor = Colors.red;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
      color: changingColor,
    );
  }
}
```